# How to return a value using Doctrine in symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I want to return Leave Type of an employee in a particular date using the following function

```
public static function getLeaveTypeInDate($date, $empId) {
    $leaveType = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('leave_type')
            ->from('EmployeeLeave')
            ->where('employee_id = ?', $empId)
            ->andWhere('applied_from = ?', $date)
            ->execute();

    return $leaveType[0];
```

But it returns Employee Name which is not directly stored in "employee_leave" table.

Answer (score 1):

In this moment you're returning an entire EmployeeLeave object by doing  `->execute()` and then  `return $leaveType[0]`

My advice is to change your query statement by replacing `->execute()` with `->fetchOne()`

Then, instead of doing `return $leaveType[0]` you could simply do `return $leaveType->getLeaveType()`